# Jquery dataTables and tablesorter together

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, datatables

I had this requirement of paginating the data being shown in the table and fetching it through ajax calls - this I accomplished by using dataTables plugin with the following configuration -

```
bServerSide : true;
sAjaxSource : <ajax_source>
bPaginate : true,
bSort:false,
bFilter:false
```

I also had a requirement of sorting this data client side, i.e. only on the current page and not the whole set ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262648/jquery-datatables-how-to-achieve-server-side-fetching-and-client-side-sorting)). For this I tried [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin using the following code-

```
 "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
                    $.ajax({
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "type" : "GET",
                        "url" : sSource,
                        "data" : aoData,
                        "success" : function (jsonData){
                            fnCallback(jsonData);
                            $("#companies").tablesorter();
                        }
                    });
               }
```

But to my surprise, even though the sorting works fine on the first page, as soon as I move on to the subsequent pages, as soon as I click on the column header it starts showing all the rows on the previous page as well, which is undesirable.

Can someone please explain, what might be going wrong here.

**Edit:**   `$("#companies").trigger("update");` did the trick

Comment: You're getting twice as many rows when you sort on the second page?

Comment: yes, which should not be the case as the table is paginated and the number of rows at second page should only be considered while sorting.

Comment: That's puzzling. I see quite a few items over to the right here >>> which appear to be related questions that just might help you figure this out.

Comment: $("#companies").trigger("update"); did the trick

Comment: Great! I edited your question to include your solution so people will see it. Editing your questions is perfectly acceptable for you to do in the future.

Comment: See my comment on your other question thread.  I've already fought this battle on quite a few more records, and it's not as difficult as you think.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with the following change -
bringing the tablesorter initialisation out

```
 $("#companies").tablesorter();
```

and trigger update after every ajax call.

```
"success" : function (jsonData) {
    fnCallback(jsonData);
    $("#companies").trigger("update");
}
```