# jQuery Datatable change search from serverside leaving sorting,pagination on serverside

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable server side processing. Now I want to change the search functionality from server side to page specific leaving others like pagination and sorting on server side. How to achieve this?

Comment: that sounds as if you would first generate all rows on server, then apply filter client side, return back the filtered row set to the server, which would then return a page worth of sorted rows? This sounds like a very strange workflow. Maybe there is another way to accomplish what you need. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like that by combining datatables and tablesorter like in this answer

[Jquery dataTables and tablesorter together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268791/jquery-datatables-and-tablesorter-together)